# data communication between Windows .NET (or LabVIEW) application and Linux c/c application

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I want to make a user interface on C#.NET or LabVIEW and wirelessly(WLAN) communicate with an application for hardware control running on linux based Single Board Computer. What is the best and easy way to get it done?

NOTE: linux based application will be written in C/C++.

Comment: Will this C++ Application have a running socket?

Comment: yes it will have a running socket

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/